# How to disable button to avoid multiple clicks in zk java

Tags: zk

I am showing the message box on click on of the button. If I double click the message box is showing twice.

I tried by setting autodisable="self", But still the issue persists.

Is there any way I can check whether the Message box is displaying or not.If it is displaying I will not call it again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a boolean variable messageBoxVisible and change its status clicking the button. Is the messagebox, then open the messagebox only if the variable is false.

Comment: Implemented in the same way,Thanks.

Comment: it's a bit unusual, I tried a simple case http://zkfiddle.org/sample/48leuh/1-autodisable-button-with-messagebox and autodisable="self" successfully prevents double clicking for me... can you provide an example that has the problem you describe? don't forget to mention the ZK version